# C# Execute command Line error with space

Tags: c#, command, line, execute

Here is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
String mypath = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.ToString();
mypath = mypath.Substring(0, mypath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
startInfo.Arguments = "/k "+
    string.Format("\"{0}\"" + " " + ProcessIds[clientlist.SelectedIndex] + " " + "\"{1}\"",
                  mypath + "\\MIMT.exe",
                  mypath + "\\No.Ankama.dll");
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

And now the result:

[image: screenshot]

Looks like the space is a problem, despite the quote, I do not understand.

Comment: take the arguements line, make it a string, set a breakpoint on the string and read it's value. Point startInfo.Arguements to that string. The breakpoint should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: I have already do this it does not do me, because all are correct, if i copy the arguments value on cmd, that's works. But it doesn't works with process.Start()

http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/302390Sanstitre.png if i copy this directly in console , it's work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse the path and file name with `Substring()` or similar methods.

Use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` and `Path.Combine()`.

```
string mypath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string exeFile = Path.Combine(mypath, "MIMT.exe");
string dllFile = Path.Combine(mypath, "No.Ankama.dll");
startInfo.Arguments = "/k \""+ exeFile + "\" " + ProcessIds[clientlist.SelectedIndex] 
    + " \"" + dllFile + "\"";
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You can run your exe file directly without using the cmd.exe.

```
startInfo.FileName = exeFile;
startInfo.Arguments = ProcessIds[clientlist.SelectedIndex] + " \"" + dllFile + "\"";
```

Comment: This does not change even if the code is cleaner like this

Comment: What does the error message state?
Are you trying to start your MIMT.exe? Why do you need the cmd.exe? You could start your process directly.